# How can I clean the build volume?

Tags: convox

My build volume is currently at 1TB as I've had to increase it several times over the years to handle out of space errors. Is there anyway I can remove old builds so I can have a smaller build volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's interesting, what Rack version are you running?  Convox runs a `docker image prune` every day to help remove older (>96h), unused images.  (https://github.com/convox/rack/blob/master/provider/aws/formation/rack.json#L1402)

If you perform a `convox instances keyroll` that would do a rolling refresh of all your instances to wipe out your cache completely and start fresh if that would help.